# How to make CodeBlocks see Windows kits, SDK

Tags: c++11, codeblocks

So I'm coding with CodeBlocks Ide...how do I make code blocks to see that I have the windows kit on my machine so that CodeBlocks can use the necessary headers it needs to build my projects?

I already went into compiler settings, linker settings, and link libraries and added "C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include "
but still, it seems CodeBlocks are not reading in the libraries.

what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include` is not where the libraries
are. It's where the header files of the libraries are.

Header files (`*.h`) are for the compiler, so it knows the signatures of
the library functions and can recognise calls to them.

Libraries (`*.dll`,`*.lib`) are for the linker, so it can extract from
them the definitions of the things declared in the header files and
link them into your program, so it works.

The libraries you need will be under `C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\um\ARCH`,
where `ARCH` is your target architecture = `x86` or `x64`.

You must of course be using Microsoft's compiler and linker (from the SDK) to build programs using the SDK libraries.

Comment: ok so let's say I want to use MinGW compiler, how do I get all the necessary headers, at the moment the header I need is commdlg.h and using a variable in that header the compiler is giving me the error .... was not declared in this scope...

Comment: @user3374754 That is an entirely different problem that can't be clearly stated or answered in comments. You don't want to use the Windows SDK in C::B at all, so delete this question and ask another one about the actual problem, after reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)